# Split a collection of double by size of its contents

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a collection of numbers (Collection) and it can be any size and contain negative and positive numbers. I am trying to split it up based on some criteria. starting at the first number in the collection I want to make a collection while that number is above -180 and below 180. Any numbers above 180 will go in a new collection or any numbers below -180 will go in an new collection. If the numbers become within the acceptable parameters again those will go in a new collection again. the problem is the collections need to stay in order.

For example.

Take a collection of 100:

- the first 50 is between 180 and -180.
- the next 20 are below -180
- the next 20 are above 180
- the last 10 are between 180 and -180

From the collection above I should now have 4 separate collection in the same order as the original 1 collection.

- First collection numbers in original order between 180 and -180
- second collection numbers in original order below -180
- third collection numbers in original order above 180
- fourth collection numbers in original order between 180 and -180

I have made an attempt, what I have doesn't work and is a nasty mess of if statements. I don't know linq very well but I think there may be a more elegant solution using that. Can anyone help me out here either with showing me how to create a linq statement or suggestions on how to get my if statements to work if that is the best way.

```
Collection<Tuple<Collection<double>, int>> collectionOfDataSets = new Collection<Tuple<Collection<double>, int>>();
Collection<double> newDataSet = new Collection<double>();
for (int i = 0; i < dataSet.Count; i++) {
    if (dataSet[i] < 180 && dataSet[i] > -180) {
        newDataSet.Add(dataSet[i]);
    } else {
        Tuple<Collection<double>, int> lastEntry = collectionOfDataSets.LastOrDefault(b => b.Item2 == i--);
        if (lastEntry != null){
            lastEntry.Item1.Add(dataSet[i]);
        }
        double lastInLastCollection = collectionOfDataSets.ElementAtOrDefault(collectionOfDataSets.Count).Item1.Last();
        if (newDataSet.Count > 0 && lastInLastCollection!= dataSet[i]){
            collectionOfDataSets.Add(new Tuple<Collection<double>, int>(newDataSet, i));                        
        }
        newDataSet = new Collection<double>();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: what's the difference between first and forth collection?

Comment: The first and fourth collection are made up of the same type but it is the collection of that type after the collection of the previous type. For example in the collection {1,6,2,5,-200,195,4,2,190,305} there would be 5 separate collections returned. the first one {1,6,2,5} the second one{-200} the third one{195} the fourth one{4,2} the fifth one{190,305}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is complicated. I'll first state and solve a simpler problem, then use the same method to solve your original problem.

---

I want to split a list of numbers into *contiguous* groups of even and odd numbers.  For example, given the list `2,2,4,3,6,2` I would split it into *three* groups `[2,2,4], [3], [6,2]`

This can be done concisely with a [GroupAdjacentBy](https://gist.github.com/2277055) method

```
> var numbers = new List<int>{2,2,4,3,6,2};
> numbers.GroupAdjacentBy(x => x % 2)
[[2,2,4], [3], [6,2]]
```

---

To solve your problem, simply replace the even-odd classifying function above with your classification function:

```
> var points = new List<int>{-180,180};
> var f = new Func<int,int>(x => points.BinarySearch(x));
> var numbers = new List<int>{6,-50,100,190,200,20};
> numbers.GroupAdjacentBy(f)
[[6,-50,100], [190,200], [20]]
```

Comment: Is dump a 3rd party extension in LINQ? I was not able to get it to work. With having to compile with strict rules it will not let me run it as it is so I will have to try and change it so I can. It is complaining about nested generic type (CA1006: Mircosoft.Design) This looks like a nice generic design and would be helpful in other places too. I hope I can get it working. thank you.

Comment: The Dump method is an extension in [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). I don't know how to print lists in Vanilla C#.

Comment: I have been using this solution for a little bit now, is it possible to add a case for when the difference between the previous number and the next number is greater then 300 with this function?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the collections to be updated as soon as the values change why don;t you use properties? Something like

```
// your original collection
public IList<double> OriginalValues; //= new List<double> { -1000, 5, 7 1000 };

public IList<double> BelowMinus180
{
   get { return OriginalValues.Where(x => x < -180).ToList().AsReadOnly(); }
}

public IList<double> BetweenMinus180And180
{
   get { return OriginalValues.Where(x => x >= -180 && x <= 180).ToList().AsReadOnly(); }
}

public IList<double> Above180
{
   get { return OriginalValues.Where(x => x > 180).ToList().AsReadOnly(); }
}
```

Comment: I originally thought of something like this but the problem is as an end result I need a collection of collections (Collection<Collection<double>>) where if I were to go through every value one by one it would be in the same order as the original collection. There are times when a collection might need to be split  into 30 sub collections or maybe there is no need to split a certain collection at all. It depends on the original collection.

Comment: @scottlafoy You sure did not include that comment in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<List<T>> PartitionBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    bool lastPass = true;
    return seq.Aggregate(new List<List<T>>(), (partitions, item) =>
    {
        bool inc = predicate(item);
        if (inc == lastPass)
        {
            if (partitions.Count == 0)
            {
                partitions.Add(new List<T>());
            }
            partitions.Last().Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            partitions.Add(new List<T> { item });
        }
        lastPass = inc;
        return partitions;
    });
}
```

You can then use:

```
List<List<double>> segments = newDataSet.PartitionBy(d => d > -180 && d < 180);
```

Comment: I like the idea of this, but I can't figure out how to extend list without breaking the strict rules visual studio is running under. I have tried to turn it into a method and visual studios still does not like it. It has a problem with passing the delegates in I believe.

Comment: @scottlafoy - I'm not sure what you mean by 'extend list' or turning this into a method, since it already is a method. This should compile on .Net 3.5 or later unless you have some unusual project-specific settings.

Comment: @scottlafoy - You have to put extenstion method inside `public static class`. Then do not forget to declare proper namespace inside the class where you want to use that extension,

Comment: This works very well, except since I am running with strict rules I have to suppress: "Microsoft.Design", "CA1002:DoNotExposeGenericLists" and "Microsoft.Design", "CA1006:DoNotNestGenericTypesInMemberSignatures" I am trying to figure out how to adjust it so it works. As is when I put a collection of 513 in the combined count of the collections returned is 513 in what appears correct order.

Answer (score 0):

How about this possible solution using two passes. In the first pass we find the indices were a change occurs, and in the second pass we do the actual partitioning. 
First an auxiliary method to determine the category:

```
    protected int DetermineCategory(double number)
    {
        if (number < 180 && number > -180)
            return 0;
        else if (number < -180)
            return 1;
        else
            return 2;
    }
```

And then the actual algorithm:

```
    List<int> indices = new List<int>();
    int currentCategory = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
    {
        int newCat = DetermineCategory(numbers[i]);
        if (newCat != currentCategory)
        {
            indices.Add(i);
            currentCategory = newCat;
        }
    }
    List<List<double>> collections = new List<List<double>>(indices.Count);
    for (int i = 1; i < indices.Count; ++i)
        collections.Add(new List<double>(
            numbers.Skip(indices[i - 1]).Take(indices[i] - indices[i - 1])));
```

Comment: Awesome! So far this seems to look like it is going to work. I will implement it when I get in and let everyone know know. Thanks.

Comment: I have given it a try and it seems very close. The numbers seem to be in order, but I am missing a couple. In a collection of 513 after adding up all the sub collections I only had 483 so it is dropping 30 on me some where. I will see if I can figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new answer based on the new info you provided. I hope this time I will be closer to what you need

```
public IEnumerable<IList<double>> GetCollectionOfCollections(IList<double> values, IList<double> boundries)
{
    var ordered = values.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < boundries.Count; i++)
    {
        var collection = ordered.Where(x => x < boundries[i]).ToList();
        if (collection.Count > 0)
        {
            ordered = ordered.Except(collection).ToList();
            yield return collection.ToList();
        }
    }
    if (ordered.Count() > 0)
    {
        yield return ordered;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One method with linq. Untested but should work

```
var firstSet = dataSet.TakeWhile(x=>x>-180&&x<180);
var totalCount = firstSet.Count();
var secondSet = dataSet.Skip(totalCount).TakeWhile(x=>x<-180);
totalCount+=secondSet.Count();
var thirdSet = dataSet.Skip(totalCount).TakeWhile(x=>x>180);
totalCount += thirdSet.Count();
var fourthSet = dataSet.Skip(totalCount);
```